# How to send data as input with IOConnectCallStructMethod

Tags: c++, swift, iokit, ipados, driverkit

I'm trying to use `IOConnectCallStructMethod` so send data in the input field to talk to my driver in DriverKit (iPadOS)

In this particular method I send an input and I expect getting an output. But ignore the output for now.

In my case `IOConnectCallStructMethod` is called with Swift:

```
var input:[UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 200)
for i in 0..<200 {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        input[i] = UInt8(i)
    }
}
let arraySize:Int = input.count;
var outputSize = MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size * arraySize
var output:[UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: arraySize)

let inputSize = MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size * input.count

let ret = IOConnectCallStructMethod(connection, Selector.mySelector.rawValue, &input, inputSize, &output, &outputSize)
```

This is the dispatch in the external method:

```
[ExternalMethodType_MyMethodRequest] =
{
    .function = (IOUserClientMethodFunction) &Client::StaticHandleRequest,
    .checkCompletionExists = false,
    .checkScalarInputCount = 0,
    .checkStructureInputSize = 200,
    .checkScalarOutputCount = 0,
    .checkStructureOutputSize = 200,
},
```

The `ExternalMethod` gets called and when I try to access to the input data with this:

```
char* input = nullptr;
size_t length = 0;
if (arguments->structureInput != nullptr)
{
    input = (char*)arguments->structureInput->getBytesNoCopy();
    length = arguments->structureInput->getLength();
    Log("Input: %s", input);
    Log("length: %zu", length);
}
```

If I check the variable `input` with a breakpoint the value is always `""` and the length is `200`

I tried adding the input in a struct, same result.
I tried using `IOConnectCallMethod`, same result.

The only alternative I can do it's making the input data extra big to force the system to use the descriptor instead of the OSData, but the input in this case would be always much smaller, so not sure if the best way to go.

Interestingly if I print the output of input with:

```
#define Log(fmt, ...) os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "NullDriver - " fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

It will give me `private`:

```
NullDriver - Input: <private>
```

Maybe the data is actually there but I can't see it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `%s` to log the data? That treats it as a nul-terminated string (UTF-8, usually). I don't have much experience with Swift, but it looks like you're sending arbitrary bytes, not a human readable string. In particular, your first byte is 0, so that's an empty C string. Seems like something like `%02x %02x %02x %02x` with `input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3]` would be more appropriate for your data. To fix the `<private>` issue when using `%s`, use `%{public}s`. (but read the `os_log` documentation on the privacy ramifications of this before you ship it)

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I didn't know, I was trying to print the full string, but I guess ( as you clarify ) it's not possible and rather I should print individual values per index.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in way to print an array of integers in a predefined human readable form in `os_log` or common C & C++ formatting as far as I'm aware. So this works now?

Comment: Yes, I think it was working all the time, it's just a matter that I thought I didn't have anything

Comment: Sidenote, to log raw bytes, you might want to do `os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "%.*P", length, input);`

Answer (score 2):

Further to discussion in comments:

There is no issue here with the way the data is being sent from app to dext, but rather with the way it is being logged/printed: a format string of `%s` is not a suitable way of printing the contents of a byte array. That treats it as a nul-terminated string (UTF-8, usually). It looks like you're sending arbitrary bytes, not a human readable string. In particular, your first byte is 0, which is how an empty C string is represented, and hence your empty output.

A format string such as `"%02x %02x %02x %02x"` with arguments `input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3]` would be more appropriate for printing the first 4 bytes; you'll have to do this in a loop, possibly writing to a buffer using `snprintf` before sending it to the system log, to print the entire array.

Separately: to fix the `<private>` issue when using `%s`, use `%{public}s`. (but read the `os_log` documentation on the privacy ramifications of this before you ship it)

Answer (score 1):

I think the data is there but I can't see it.

If I do:

```
char realInput[200];
memcpy(realInput, input, 200);
```

When I loop printing in the debugger: `realInput[i]` I get my precious data

Comment: You don't have to actually copy the data to an array. You can loop over the `input` pointer and print them directly.